# How to hide/show a register with djangoadmin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, user-controls, django-queryset

I have a model with customers
in my front I have a combobox with the list of my customers.

how I can in djangoadmin hide or show this customers?

I think it could be a checkbox like "this customer is active/inactive"
but how can I solve this with djangoAdmin?

I think it could be a checkbox like "this customer is active/inactive"
but how can I solve this with djangoAdmin?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the field in your customer column called `is_active` as a boolean field in your model which you can edit from djangoadmin.

Comment: Sure it work! I did this code in my model: 
class CustomerManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(is_active=True)
class Customer(models.model):
is_active = True

but I want to allow in the admin to activate and deactivate customers, not dissapear, when I set in false, this dissapear from djangoadmin (I think it deleted) and srry for my bad english

Comment: I got the wrong idea, Can you check the answer now?